# How do you use a bean from an another class in a class?

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

Using xml, I was able to define a common xml file, where i can put common bean which are used for other differect condig file.
I move my config to psring java config, how to achieve this  with java config?

let's say I have my common class as :

```
@Configuration
public class Common {
    @Bean
    public A a(){
        return new A();
    }
}
```

and I want to use it as

```
@Configuration
public class AConfig {

    @Bean
    public ABB abb(){
        ABB abb = new ABB();
        //TODO abb.set  ????
        return abb;
    }
}
```

The TODO part is missing,  I want to use the a() from the common class.
Is that possible?

Comment: You should be able to autowire like a regular dependency injection `@Autowired` into `Aconfig` class and use that reference

Comment: I thought about that, but i wasn't sure, let me try it.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach is just to 'Autowire' in a private member like this:

```
@Configuration
public class AConfig {

    @Autowire
    private A myA;

    @Bean
    public ABB abb(){
        ABB abb = new ABB();
        abb.setA(myA);  // or MUCH better, make the A member of ABB private final and overload a construtor
        return abb;
    }
}
```

The reason this works is that AConfig is a Bean too.  It has to be constructed by the Spring Bean Factory.  After construction, the Post Construction activities take place - one of those being processing post construction annotations such as Autowired.  So 'myA' will be set before it is used in the @Bean annotated method.

Answer (score 2):

From the `@Import` annotation Javadoc:

```
 * <p>Provides functionality equivalent to the {@code <import/>} element in Spring XML.
 * Only supported for classes annotated with {@code @Configuration} or declaring at least
 * one {@link Bean @Bean} method, as well as {@link ImportSelector} and
 * {@link ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar} implementations.
 *
 * <p>{@code @Bean} definitions declared in imported {@code @Configuration} classes
 * should be accessed by using {@link org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired @Autowired}
 * injection. Either the bean itself can be autowired, or the configuration class instance
 * declaring the bean can be autowired. The latter approach allows for explicit,
 * IDE-friendly navigation between {@code @Configuration} class methods.
 *
 * <p>May be declared at the class level or as a meta-annotation.
 *
 * <p>If XML or other non-{@code @Configuration} bean definition resources need to be
 * imported, use {@link ImportResource @ImportResource}
```

I presume that if you import the `@Configuration` class itself, the "latter approach", you'd then just explicitly call the `@Bean` method on the imported class, e.g.

```
@Configuration
@Import(BarConfiguration.class)
public class FooConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private BarConfiguration barConfiguration;

    @Bean 
    public Foo foo() {
       Foo foo = new Foo();
       foo.setBar(barConfiguration.bar());
       return foo;
    }
}
```